# cannot remove com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist

Tags: skype

I am on High Sierra (MacOS 10.13.6) and I am failing to remove `com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist` which is in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`

```
ls -l
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 me  staff    1  8 Oct 17:57 com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist
```

So I fail to see why I cannot.  Yet:

```
rm -r com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist
remove com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist? y
rm: com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist: Operation not permitted
```

similarly,

```
sudo rm com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist
Password:
remove com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist? y
rm: com.skype.skype.shareagent.plist: Operation not permitted
```

I rebooted in single user mode, used `chflags noschg` and tried to remove the file with no success.  What I did manage to do as single user was to basically delete the content of the file with vim.  I cannot rename the file BTW.

Any idea of (1) what is going on and (2) how I delete said file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I realised the folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents` was locked -- I changed that and I could remove the file.  Mystery solved.

Comment: how did you unlock it ?

Comment: with the finder -- `get info`